# Как обратится к классу, который находится внутри другого класса

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Доброе утро!) Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня .product__item используется в нескольких блоках, как указать в js, что добавлять класс нужно лишь тому у кого родитель .product-page-items ??

Такая структура html:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой js:

```
$('.icon-th-list').on('click', function(){   

if ($(this).parent('.product-page-items')) {

    $('.product__item').addClass('list');

}
```

});

Но он добавляет класс всем блокам, которые содержат внутри классы product__item

Comment: Код принято постить в текстовом виде... в чуть более сложном случае никто не станет с картинки перепиисывать код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не работает по двум причинам... `$(this)` - это тот элемент, который запустил функцию (на который кликнули). `.parent("селектор")` - возвращает родительский элемент, если он совпадает с селектором, или сам элемент, если родитель не подходит. А это в любом случае в логическом контексте будет true.

Но даже если бы получилось правильно отфильтровать блоки с нужным родителем, затем всё всё равно добавляете класс всем: `$('.product__item').addClass('list');`

Можно было проверять родителя каждого блока, но есть простые CSS-селекторы:

• `.class1 .class2` - через пробел, означает, что второй может быть где угодно внутри первого,

• `.class1 > .class2` - только те class2, которые находятся непосредственно среди дочерних элементов class1. Чаще всего используется вариант с пробелом, т.к. этот придется переделать, если в будущем захочется изменить разметку.

```js
$('.icon-th-list').on('click', function() {
  $('.product-page-items .product__item').addClass('list');
});
```

```css
.list { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="icon-th-list">.......</button>

<div class="product-page-items">
  <div class="product__item">Покрасить</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="product__item">Не покрасить</div>
</div>
```

А "ручная" проверка родителей выглядела бы так:

```js
$('.icon-th-list').on('click', function() {
  // Функция вызывается в контексте $('.icon-th-list'). Здесь $(this) — '.icon-th-list'

  $('.product__item').each(function(){
    // У этой функции контекст вызова другой: 
    // Здесь $(this) - очередной '.product__item' внутри каждой проверки.

    if( $(this).closest('.product-page-items').length > 0 ){ 
     // можно без > 0 — любое число кроме 0, в логическом контексте будет true
     // $(this).parent().hasClass('.product-page-items')
      $(this).addClass('list');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.list { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="icon-th-list">.......</button>

<div class="product-page-items">
  <div class="product__item">Покрасить</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="product__item">Не покрасить</div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое)))